# When kicking a managed EKS cluster using a yaml config file, what does desiredCapacity in ClusterConfig specify?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, eksctl

I am a k8s and EKS noob.
I'm trying to kick a cluster and keep meeting the *desiredCapacity* key. I just cannot find where it is documented.
Don't bother pointing to the [schema](https://eksctl.io/usage/schema/#nodeGroups-desiredCapacity), it's not described there.

Answer (score 1):

`When kicking a managed EKS cluster using a yaml config file, what does desiredCapacity in ClusterConfig specify?`

This field is actually used by ASG; where it means your cluster will start by launching the **desired capacity** (# of EC2 instance), and ASG will monitor and replace any instance that has health issue to maintain the **desired capacity** for your cluster.